# Open multidatespicker on button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I have the following code working with a simple `datepicker`;
when I click on the button the picker displayed.

I need this to be work with a `multidatespicker`:

**Simple datepicker JS script.**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date').datepicker();
    $('#btnRepercute').click(function() {
          $('#date').datepicker('show');
      });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML input fields.**

```
<input type="button" value="Répercuter" class="button" id="btnRepercute"/>
<input type="text" id="date" class="hidden" />
```

**Attempts so far with multidatespicker**

```
$('#date').multiDatesPicker();
$('#btnRepercute').click(function() {
      $('#date').multiDatesPicker();
});
```

Nothing happens, no errors in the console.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's multiDatesPicker? If it's a plugin you may want to link to the source.

Comment: It's a simple multi dates picker : http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to unregister the `datepicker` event and then attach the `multiDatesPicker` event , after that focus the element

```
$('#btnRepercute').click(function() {

  $("#date").datepicker( "destroy" );
 $('#date').multiDatesPicker();
 $('#date').focus();
});
```

Hope it works fine